# Showing that Random Variables are independent with order statistics (no jpdf given)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

> Let $X_1$,$X_2$ be iid r.v, with Exp(a) distribution. Show that 
>   $X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(1)}$ are independent and find their
>   distributions. ($X_{(1)}$ denotes the order statistic)

Their individual distributions can be easily found, where $X_{(2)}-X_{(1)} \in Exp(a)$ and $X_{(1)} \in Exp(a/2)$. I am struggling to show independence though, since I would think that this would require knowing the joint distribution of  $X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(1)}$. Am I missing something obvious?

I am mostly interested in hints, not full solutions if possible!

Comment: Can you compute the joint PDF of $(X_{(1)},X_{(2)})$? The rest follows by a change of variable.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240822/let-u-operatornamemin-x-y-and-v-operatornamemax-x-y-show-that?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Try working the problem a second time, replacing the exponential distributions with uniform distributions on $[0,1]$.  (call these variables $Y$ instead of $X$). Stare at 
$$
P(Y_{(2)}-Y_{(1)} > \alpha | Y{(1)} = y)
$$
and see if that expression contains a $y$.

Now with your exponential $X$s, stare at
$$
P(X_{(2)}-X_{(1)} > \alpha | X{(1)} = x)
$$

The special thing about the exponential distribution is how that expression depends on $x$.

Answer (score 2):

The joint probability density function is: $$\quad f_{[X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}]}(y,z)
\\ = f_{[X_{(1)},X_{(2)}]}(y,z+y)~~
\\ = 2~f_X(y)~f_X(z+y)
$$

If we have independence this will be equal to the product: $$f_{X_{(1)}}(y)~f_{[X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}]}(z)$$

Is it?

Comment: It is! Thanks a lot!