# Show that $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(2)}−X_{(1)}$ are independent, and determine their distributions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, order-statistics

> Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent, $\text{Exp}(a)$-distributed random variables. Show that $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(2)}−X_{(1)}$ are independent, and determine their distributions.

Although it looks like a duplicate([Old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950648/showing-that-random-variables-are-independent-with-order-statistics-no-jpdf-giv)) I have a different question.
I'm more concerned about the bounds of integration.

---

I found the joint to be: $$f_{U, V}(u,v)=2a^2e^{-a(2u+v)},  \quad \text{ with } \quad  U=X_{(1)} , V= X_{(2)} - X_{(1)} $$

Hypothetically speaking, I think that the bounds are found by writing:
$X_{(1)}=U$ then I know automatically that $0\le U\le\infty$.

But for $V$, I think I do a similar thing with $X_{(2)}=V+U$, $ 0\le V+U \le \infty$ $ \implies -V\le U \le \infty $

**Sorry about the fundamentality of this question, I feel like because of that I'm getting:**

$X_{(2)} - X_{(1)}\sim \text{Exp}(a)$ which is true,
but  for $f_U(u)=2ae^{-au}$ instead of $f_U(u)=\frac{a}{2}e^{-\frac{a}{2}u}$

**Questions:**

How to find the bounds of integration? Is my way of doing it correct?
Furthermore, how do you work with this stuff without having to do the transformations with the jacobians?

Comment: Similar question with $a=1$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240822/let-u-operatornamemin-x-y-and-v-operatornamemax-x-y-show-that?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: I checked it but couldn't find anything to answer my question

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. In any case, $X_2-X_1$ can't be an exponential, since it doesn't have always positive sign. You might want to write $X_1=aY_1$, $X_2=aY_2$ with $Y_i$ being $Exp(1)$ and do the calculations there first, just to avoid the annoying parameter $a$ and clear your ideas

Comment: ah I see sorry. In the question the difference between $X_i$ and $X_{(i)}$ was never defined, I didn't realize the they were different objects.

Comment: @MahamadA.Kanouté Regarding "how do you work with this stuff without having to do the transformations with the jacobians?", my linked post does have the answers.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I did get it now. But more importantly, I always fail when taking the marginal of such joints. Hence my question. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough

Comment: The information $-V\le U \le \infty$ is useless because both $U$ and $V$ are non-negative by definition. Please elaborate on how you arrived at $f_U(u)=\frac{a}{2}e^{-\frac{a}{2}u}$ for people to help pointing out where you've gone wrong.